# Touch mode in WPF Applications

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-interface, touch

Some of you may have noticed that Office 2013 contains a new feature called touch mode.

[image: Touch&Mouse Office 2013]

And this is how it looks
[image]

I was wondering if i could achieve the same in WPF. Any ideas?

Comment: Ah.. now I see... That's just a `ScaleTransform` to 1.2 or something.

Comment: the space between the commands and the size of the commands increases a bit.

Comment: see my edited comment. You need to apply a Layout `ScaleTransform`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to add something like this (code below) to my main grid. Thank you, HighCore for pointing me into the right direction.

```
<Grid.LayoutTransform>
    <ScaleTransform x:Name="ApplicationScaleTransform"
                CenterX="0"
                CenterY="0"
                ScaleX="1.2"
                ScaleY="1.2" />
</Grid.LayoutTransform>
```

But how do I implement this in with the MVVM Pattern?

Sure, I could simply create an binding which bind ScaleX and ScaleY to an Property in my ViewModel.

But does it really belongs into the ViewModel? I mean this is clearly part of the GUI which should only be in the View.

**EDIT:**
Maybe I should bind ScaleX and ScaleY to an Property inside the XAML Codebehind (eg. MainWindow.xaml.cs) The problem is that the DataContext is already set to the ViewModel.

**EDIT2 My Solution**

The upper code snippet causes all elements to "grow". My problem with this code was that the fontsize of my textboxes was also affected. I managed to handle this unwanted behavior by defining a style for every element that should scale.

```
<ResourceDictionary>
            <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" />
            <Style TargetType="ScrollBar">
                <Setter Property="LayoutTransform" >
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ScaleTransform x:Name="ApplicationScaleTransform"
                        CenterX="0"
                        CenterY="0"
                            ScaleX="{Binding ScaleFactor, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                            ScaleY="{Binding ScaleFactor, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                         />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                <Setter Property="LayoutTransform" >
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ScaleTransform x:Name="ApplicationScaleTransform"
                        CenterX="0"
                        CenterY="0"
                            ScaleX="{Binding ScaleFactor, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                            ScaleY="{Binding ScaleFactor, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                         />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="LayoutTransform" >
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ScaleTransform x:Name="ApplicationScaleTransform"
                        CenterX="0"
                        CenterY="0"
                            ScaleX="{Binding ScaleFactor, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                            ScaleY="{Binding ScaleFactor, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                         />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries></ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
```

**Question:** This code looks a bit ugly is there a way to define the same snippet for multiply target types? e.g.

Comment: You could also create a `public bool IsTouchMode` either in the ViewModel, or as a DP in the View (as you prefer), and create a `DataTrigger` that reacts to that and modifies the `ScaleX` and `ScaleY` properties.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I guess i can't modify the ScaleX/Y Property with Setters. Because Setters work on elements (UIElement) but ScaleTransform derives from Transform which does not derive from UIElement.

Comment: or you could try to bind to this boolean Property using a valueconverter?

Comment: I bound the ScaleProperties to an double value in my ViewModel and it works well. The Scale Transformation is applied to all children of my maingrid. But how can I prevent the font size from scaling? Theres no need for a bigger fontsize when you use the application on a mobile device.